# linq query to get multiple datatable from dataset based on some condition

Tags: c#, linq, console

I have to create 2 datatable based on a column, the condition is column is null should come as one table and column is not null should come as one table

I experimented code is mentioned below. what needs to change please suggest to me.

```
 List<DataTable> resultsNull = result
   .AsEnumerable()
   .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("RFIDCode") == null && 
                  ("RFIDCode") == " " )
   .Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
   .ToList();

for exmaple the dataset have below columns
slno    rfidcode
 1      87464554645
 2      46541321321
 3                 
 4      46897646546
 5                 



 i have the above dataset as 2 datatable which should be like below


table 1
slno    rfidcode
  1     87464554645
  2     46541321321
  4     46897646546



table 2
slno    rfidcode
 3
 4
```

Comment: Typo? `("RFIDCode") == " "` will be `false`

Comment: I didn't get the point @DmitryBychenko

Comment: `.GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("RFIDCode") == null ||  row.Field<string>("RFIDCode") == " " )`

Comment: it's selecting the column which is not null also @DmitryBychenko

Comment: @NiranjanS no it isn't; it is comparing two constant but different string literals... that will always return `false`

Comment: I appreciate that this isn't the question, but : unsolicited observation; `DataTable` is *not* a friendly, or efficient, API; it isn't the recommended API for most scenarios (unless you're writing ad-hoc query tooling where the schema is unknown). This whole thing would be a *lot* simpler if you were using POCOs instead of `DataTable`. Ultimately, `DataSet` was the API for migrating COM ADO record-set code (often from VB6), back in  early .NET; **much better** APIs have largely replaced it since then; think "EF", "Dapper", etc

Comment: i have edited my question with example. please have a look and suggest me how get required output @MarcGravell

Comment: well, @DmitryBychenko already kinda gave you that; personally, I'd go with `.GroupBy(row => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(row.Field<string>("RFIDCode")))`, but same thing broadly speaking

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you so much i got the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *looks* like you want to group by whether or not the `RFIDCode` column, a `string`, is null/empty. As such, you could try:

```cs
.GroupBy(row => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(row.Field<string>("RFIDCode")))
```